# GDS Yen's k algo in Noe4j not giving the desired output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j i'm using GDS' Yen's k-algo to get top 3 shortest path between two nodes.

but im having hard time projecting my graph into memory thus Yen's k alog not giving me my desired output.

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
  'test1',
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  {Director_In: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}, Shareholder_In: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}}
  )
YIELD
  graphName AS graph, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipCount AS rels
```

this gives me result but with virtual relationship having nagative cost like `PATH_0, PATH_1 PATH_2...` (some guy on discord suggested me to use `Undirected` orientation) [image: virtual relationships]

but when i'm using cupher projection im getting no result..

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
  'persons',
  'MATCH (n) RETURN id(n) AS id',
  'MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, type(r) AS type')
YIELD
  graphName AS graph, nodeQuery, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipQuery, relationshipCount AS rels
```

and below is my cypher query

```
MATCH (source:A {prop: 1}), (target:B {prop: 3})
CALL gds.shortestPath.yens.stream('persons', {
sourceNode: source,
targetNode: target, 
k:4
})
YIELD index, sourceNode, targetNode, totalCost, nodeIds, costs, path
RETURN
index,
gds.util.asNode(sourceNode).name AS sourceNodeName,
gds.util.asNode(targetNode).name AS targetNodeName,
totalCost,
[nodeId IN nodeIds | gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name] AS nodeNames,
costs,
nodes(path) as path
```

PS:- when im using normal `shortestPath` i get the desired result.

```
MATCH path = shortestPath((start:A)-[*]-(end:B))
where elementId(start) = "1:x:4" and elementId(end) = "124:x:123"
```

i get my desired output from the above query.[image: this is the shortest path]

How should i project my graph so that i can get the desired result?

(*also my graph is not weighted*)

Comment: The simplest reason why your query doesn't return anything is that your `MATCH` statement isn't returning two nodes. Did you check that your graph contains `prop:1` and `prop:3`? They could, for example, be in the graph as `"1"` and `"3"`.